# PhantomJS expected an indentifier but found 'local' insted

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Hi im insstall phantom js and create local.js file contains next code

```
var page = new WebPage(),
system = require('system'),
adress

if(system.args.length < 2){
    console.log("need adress");
    phantom.exit();

} else{
        console.log("im running")
        phantom.exit();
}
```

but wwen im runnin code in comand line im have error

```
phantomjs> local.js
expected an indentifier but found 'local' insted
phantomjs://repl-input:1 in global code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not running your script file but you're trying to access a variable called `local` which would be an object with a property `js`. When you run `phantomjs` this way is like a JavaScript console: you're executing JavaScript code.

If you want to run a script file you need to use the command-line interface (CLI) as follows:

> phantomjs local.js